# "on-learning-japanese-from-anime-manga" is this question off topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[アニメと漫画で日本語を勉強することについて (On learning Japanese from anime/manga)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/215/on-learning-japanese-from-anime-manga/218#218)

ran into this question, and wanted clarification if this should be considered off-topic or on topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me like it is in a bit of a gray area, but could be rephrased to be on topic as the gist of the question could be rewritten as follows:

> How useful is anime / managa for learning conversational Japanese?

Which I feel would be a valid question since we can likely have some valid targeted responses to the question. Additionally, it should be a one-off question that doesn't need to be repeated where as a question along the lines of:

> Is [name] a good [anime / managa] for learning Japanese?

Is a pattern that could come up many times.

Comment: Given that "How useful is anime / managa for learning conversational Japanese?" doesn't have an answer... no... that's bad. Perhaps "Does anyone have a manga to practice vocabulary at roughly the N3 level?" or "Are there any kana-only manga?"

Comment: i think How useful is anime for learning japanese does have an answer.  If you look back at that thread, the answers that are there are along those lines.  Conversely, i think your question of which manga to use to practice N3 kanji is more of a resource question and would be off-topic (if that is how we are handling resource questions)

Comment: @jkerian - It still seems like a phrasing issue of the question as opposed to the nature of the question though. As @Mark noted it is generating good answers that are relevant which would imply that it is conceptually a good question. Also, likely a common one that we would get lots of variations on in the public beta.

Comment: No... it's not a phrasing issue. It fundamentally changes what is being asked. To start, "How useful is anime/manga for learning conversational japanese?" is insanely subjective. If there isn't a right answer, it's not a good question.

Comment: @Mark: Personally, I don't think all resource questions are offtopic... just all of the ones that have been asked so far.

Answer (score -1):

It's not about the language itself, so IMO it's off-topic.

Comment: But wouldn't it kind of fall under the usage of the language?

Comment: No. Usage of the language would be "I found this phrase in a manga: xxxxxxxx. What does it mean and how do I use it?". Meanwhile, asking about learning resources will be too subjective.